# Would Pantaar have done what he did for anyone?

Tags: character-motivation, king-of-katoren

In *Koning van Katoren* (*King of Katoren*) by Jan Terlouw, Stach must complete seven quests to become the King of Katoren.

One of the quests involves a sorcerer, Pantaar, who terrorizes the town of Equilibria, by demanding sacrifices from them. Each and every day, he visits one of their homes and demands a gift. If he deems it "heavy enough" — which it is if parting with it really hurts the owner — he will take it, but if not, he will take something else instead.

*Warning: spoiler for the outcome of this quest.*

> When Stach confronts him, after having been taken as a sacrifice himself, Pantaar reveals that he feeds the sacrifices to a fire that will destroy all of Equilibria if not fed daily.
>
>  Having first convinced Pantaar to let him go, Stach returns voluntarily to sacrifice himself to the flames, since a voluntary sacrifice will satisfy the flames "for a hundred times a hundred thousand years".
>  This is understandably a hard decision for Stach, not just because his life is at stake, but also because if he sacrifices himself, he can't be king, but if he doesn't, he feels he *shouldn't* become king.
>  After a some discussion between Stach and Pantaar, the latter asking why Stach would sacrifice himself for people Pantaar deems not worthy of it. Finally, stating "I demand the right to be mad. Accept, O fire, this small sacrifice", Pantaar sacrifices himself to the flames.

**Would he have done so for anyone who had offered to do what Stach offered to do?**

In other words (spoilers again),

> was he destined to sacrifice himself whenever someone offered themselves as a voluntary sacrifice? Or did his conversation with Stach, or the fact that Stach was young, with most of his life still ahead, convince Pantaar to sacrifice himself?